# Probability that neither of two selected members is a lawyer

Tags: probability

> Of the $700$ members of an organization, $120$ are lawyers. Two members will be selected at random. What is the probability that neither of the members selected will be a lawyer?

I know the answer is $(580\cdot 579)/(700\cdot 699)$ but I'm trying to use the complement rule to answer this question and I can't get the right answer. Why would the complement rule, $P(A)+P(\text{not }A)=1$, not work for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement of "neither is a lawyer" is "at least one is a lawyer", so you need to calculate the probability of that.  One way is to list the three cases:  the first is a lawyer and the second is not; the first is not and the second is; they are both lawyers.  These probabilities are disjoint, so can be added.  You calculate each of them the same way you did the direct approach:  for the first is a lawyer and the second is not, it is $\frac {120\cdot580}{700\cdot 699}$

Comment: The at least one is a lawyer was the missing link for me. I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use the complement rule, you'll need to consider all of the other possibilities.

You found the probability the first time around, in essence, by determining the probability of picking a non-laywer, and then picking another non-lawyer.

There are three other possibilities:

- First one picked is a lawyer, but the second isn't.
- Second one picked is a lawyer, but the first isn't.
- Both are lawyers.

These cases, along with the case that neither are lawyers, are disjoint (there's no overlap), so you can add up their probabilities and they will add up to $1$:

$$\frac{(120)(119)+(120)(580)+(580)(120)+(580)(579)}{(700)(699)} = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_{i}$ be event that ith person selected was a lawyer. So if you want to use complement rule you it would be as follows 
$$P(A_{1}^{c}\cap A_{2}^{c})=P((A_{1}\cup A_{2})^{c})=1-P(A_{1}\cup A_{2})$$